# Custom Table Cell: label changed by does not display

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell

I am having trouble with initial view of custom cell. The cellForRowAt indexPath: appears to work, but one of the labels isn't changed.

Code is quite simple. Notice the print statement and the output below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! SelectGroupCell

    var grData: (Desc: String, Sel: Bool) =  (Desc: "", Sel: false)
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        grData = groupTable[EKEntityType.event]![indexPath.row]
    } else {
        grData = groupTable[EKEntityType.reminder]![indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.loadCell(Desc: grData.Desc, Sel: grData.Sel)

    print ("\(cell.lblSelected.text) : \(cell.lblDescription.text)")

    return cell
}
```

Output of print:

```
Optional("O") : Optional("US Holidays") 
Optional("+") : Optional("Calendar") 
Optional("O") : Optional("Birthdays")
Optional("+") : Optional("New List Test")
Optional("O") : Optional("Reminders")
```

Simulator screen print:
[image: Notice the labels before the description are wrong.]

Custom cell function:

```
func loadCell(Desc: String, Sel: Bool) {
    lblDescription.text = Desc

    if Sel {
        lblSelected.text = "+"
    } else {
        lblSelected.text = "O"
    }

}
```

Rerun with print in loadCell

```
loadCell: O : US Holidays
display cell: O : US Holidays
loadCell: + : Calendar
display cell: + : Calendar
loadCell: O : Birthdays
display cell: O : Birthdays
loadCell: + : Reminders
display cell: + : Reminders
loadCell: O : New List Test
display cell: O : New List Test
```

I'm very confused.

Comment: Can you print also the value of  lblSelected.text in your loadCell function ?

Comment: Rerun with print in loadCell    loadCell: Optional("O") : Optional("US Holidays")
   Optional("O") : Optional("US Holidays")
    loadCell: Optional("+") : Optional("Calendar")
    Optional("+") : Optional("Calendar")
    loadCell: Optional("O") : Optional("Birthdays")
    Optional("O") : Optional("Birthdays")
    loadCell: Optional("O") : Optional("New List Test")
   Optional("O") : Optional("New List Test")
    loadCell: Optional("+") : Optional("Reminders")
   Optional("+") : Optional("Reminders")

Comment: Not seeing the issue xD Maybe unwrap the optionals with an exclamation point.

Comment: Updated issue with non-optional prints. I used same data as original test this time. Ignore test results in comments. Thanks.

Comment: In case my issue is not clear, the screen should show two cells with a "+" before them. Label is not showing text.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but don't understand why.

I deleted the SetSelect function in the cell logic:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    if selected {
        lblSelected.text = "+"
    } else {
        lblSelected.text = "O"
    }

}
```

Then I changed the didSelectRow in the table logic and reloaded table.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        groupTable[EKEntityType.event]![indexPath.row].Sel = true
    } else {
        groupTable[EKEntityType.reminder]![indexPath.row].Sel = true
    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Then the cell.LoadCell logic works:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! SelectGroupCell

    var grData: (Desc: String, Sel: Bool) =  (Desc: "", Sel: false)
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        grData = groupTable[EKEntityType.event]![indexPath.row]
    } else {
        grData = groupTable[EKEntityType.reminder]![indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.loadCell(Desc: grData.Desc, Sel: grData.Sel)

    return cell
}
```